# Cakephp : add more recipients before send an email

Tags: email, cakephp-2.0

I have to send an email to several recipients, but only if my current email address is marked as 'out of office'. In order to do that I will need to check the condition before sending the email and to retrieve my backups and add them in $to .

I currently managed to find a quick fix, I've modified CakeEmail, but it seems a little wrong to alter this file.

Any ideea of how I can do this without modifying CakeEmail?

Thank you,

Comment: how do you know if an email address is marked "out of office"? How did you modify CakeEmail? Can you paste the code?

Comment: You can see mu code below. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration (`core.php`) file you create a new configuration

```php
Configure:write( 'notify_people', array( 'email1@example.com' => 'Email1', 'email2@example.com' => 'Email2' );
```

Then you use the `CakeEmail::to()` to add recipients before sending an email. So you update all your `$email->to()` calls to read the configuration value instead.

```php
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->to( Configure::read( 'notify_people' ) );
//TODO: configure sender, subject etc...
//finally send the email
$email->send( $bodyOfTheMessage );
```

When you need to change the list of recipients you only have to do it once in the configuration file.

Comment: I think I didn;t make my self very clear. I already used $email->to( array( 'email1@example.com' => 'Email1', 'email2@example.com' => 'Email2' );  ... the problem appears when email2@example.com is out of office for example, for this email address I have x backups and I want to add them in $to also.  The easiest way to change this is to add $email->to( array( 'email1@example.com' => 'Email1', 'email2@example.com' => 'Email2', 'backup1@example.com' => 'Email3', 'backup2@example.com' => 'Email4' ); but this implies to change $to in all system ... I would like to change in only one place ..

Comment: OK, that's different. Read my updated answer with a proposed solution of grouping the recipients under one easily updatable Configuration value.